# Keep the parent selection state in the ui when a child element is clicked

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

When you look at the angularjs ui router sample:

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/contacts/1/item/b

Bobs item 'fax' was clicked by me but Bobs name on the left side has lost the blue square selection.

How can I fix that lost blue selection?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angular-ui-router team is working on a solution for this (actually I think it's done, just not released yet).

Until then, the best and easiest way is to expose `$state` onto the `$scope` of your navbar. Then you look for a match of the $state name and apply your selected class.

States:

```
$stateProvider.state('parentState', {});

$stateProvider.state('parentState.childState', {});
```

Scope:

```
app.controller('navCtrl', function ($scope, $state) {
  $scope.$state = $state;
});
```

View:

```
<li ng-class="{ 'activeClass': $state.includes('parentState') }">
```

Hope that works out for you.

Here's a thread on the suggested `ui-sref-active` directive:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/pull/927#issuecomment-49348331

Comment: I wait for the official release I am not in a rush :-)